VB.net - How to properly close a text file after reading so it can be opend for writing in the same application
I have a text file that I want to read into a buffer then close it. Later on in the program I want to open the same file to append to it. I get the all too familiar error, that the file can't be opened because it's being used by another process, when I try to open it to write to it.
Here is the READ code:
If File.Exists(outfile) Then
    '  Load existing CSV file into csvFIle string to be used a check for duplicates
    rdr = New StreamReader(outfile)
    csvFile = rdr.ReadToEnd
    rdr.Close()
    rdr.Dispose()
    rdr = Nothing '
End If

And this is the code to open for WRITING:
        sw = New StreamWriter(outfile, True) ' append to file
        If newFL Then   ' if the file is new then write the HEADER to the file
            If outbuff > "" Then sw.WriteLine(outbuff)
            outbuff = ""
            newFL = False
        End If

There has got to be a way to completely release the file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Nor

Why not close the writer when you're done, like you do with the read?

This question is similar to: Vb.net not closing file after reading from it. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I do close it a few lines down. I just added the read function . Without the read function everything work just fine

It is easier to simply use the static methods of the File Class.

Tried to re-create your issue and could not.
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "Test.txt")

    Dim line As String
    Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader(path)
        line = rdr.ReadLine
    End Using

    Using wrtr As New IO.StreamWriter(path, True)
        wrtr.WriteLine(line)
    End Using

Makes me suspect that the problem is in the code we aren't seeing.

As i said above the error started after I added the READ code. However I will dig around and see if there is something that may cause this issue. THanks

Let me try it with the USING command that may fix it

Yup the USING command in the read did the trick.  Thanks!!
